# How do I console.log the result of a foreach loop with a 'click' function?

Tags: javascript, html

Apologies if this is really simple but I have been researching this for a week now but can't find the right thing to type into google.

I have 3 buttons as shown below:

```js
const playerSelection = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons").forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    return e.innerHTML;
  })
});

console.log(playerSelection);
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="buttons">Rock</button>
  <button class="buttons">Paper</button>
  <button class="buttons">Scissors</button>
</div>
```

When I console.log playerSelection it only returns undefined. I want the playerSelection variable to equal the innerHTML content of whichever button I click.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: @Nico Haase: Kinda both there.

Comment: What do you expect to read?

Comment: @Nico Haase As I said in my post I have tried googling for a week now but couldn't find what I was looking for so thought it was probably time to actually post a question.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? I would assume that `forEach`  does not return anything useful, as documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/orphaned/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach - especially as the code calls `console.log` way independently from the clicks that could happen

Answer (score 2):

You log the value of the button inside the click event.

Also you should set the `type` of your buttons to `button`, otherwise they are of type `submit`, which I guess you don't want here.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".buttons").forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(e.innerHTML);
  })
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" class="buttons">Rock</button>
  <button type="button" class="buttons">Paper</button>
  <button type="button" class="buttons">Scissors</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking of [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which combines the returned results into an array.

This won't work in your case, though, as you are simply adding an event listener inside your loop. The event callback will only be triggered when the button is clicked. You'll need to write asynchronous code. For example, when a button is pressed, call a function `pickedValue()` with the result, which will then continue your program.